# What is the correct way of communicating with background script and popup script in Firefox addon development

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, message-passing, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing a firefox addon as a Firefox WebExtention. I'm having a issue with message passing with background script and popup script. Background script can read all messages but popup script can't read messages from background script.

message passing components in the background script

```html
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "msgCon"});

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(ports) {
    ports.onMessage.addListener(handleMsg);
});

function handleMsg(msg){   
        console.log("message to background loging script: " +JSON.stringify(msg));
  port.postMessage("msg from background script");
}
```

message passing components in the popup script

```html
var port;

chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.connect(tabs[0].id,{name: "msgCon"});
    addPortListner();
});

function addPortListner() {
    chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (ports) {
        ports.onMessage.addListener(handleMsg);
        port = ports;
    });
}

function handleMsg(msg){
        console.log("message to popup.js: " + JSON.stringify(msg));
  
}

function sendMeggage(msg){
    port.postMessage(msg);
}
```

I'm also communicating with content scripts from popup script and it works well

Comment: To clarify, the background script can receive messages from the popup, but not vice versa? and are these in the same file, or is the popup script being loaded using require or some other method?

Comment: Did you got a solution for this?